# mutitasking in ipod?

Tags: ipod

i am using the code`
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId;
if([player play])
bgTaskId=[[UIApplication sharedApplication];
beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:NULL];

so that when i exit my app or lock enables the music should continue playing.It works fine on simulator bot not on device. My ipod version is 4.0(8A293) and i think it supports multitasking so can anyone tel me what the problem is??? Or there is some problem in my device...
`

Comment: Like i have iphone that is 3G it not support multitasking  and my ios version is 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model 8A293 is an iPod 2g and does not support multi tasking in iOS4 unless you jailbreak and enable it.

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Apex_8A293_(iPod_touch_2G)
http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/multitasking-in-ipod-touch-2g-ios-4-confirmed-video/